# How to constraint an Event drag n drop in FullCalendar v3 to only All-Day section?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I've looking to disable Drag n Drop of "All Day" events here in below Time grid.

I need to block Drag and Drop of All-Day Events into the Timegrid view below that section. So that All-Day Events should always be droppable in All-Day section and Time based events are draggable and droppable in Time base grid section.

Can this be done with FullCalendar JS?

sample code looks like this:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/vc4u/pen/orqoeb)

**HTML:**

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    editable: true,
    eventDurationEditable: false,
    eventLimit: true,
    nowIndicator: true, 
    now: '2019-06-09T09:25:00',
    events: [
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2019-06-01',
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: '2019-06-07',
          end: '2019-06-10'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2019-06-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2019-06-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Conference',
          start: '2019-06-11',
          end: '2019-06-13'
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2019-06-12T10:30:00',
          end: '2019-06-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Lunch',
          start: '2019-06-12T12:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2019-06-12T14:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Happy Hour',
          start: '2019-06-12T17:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Dinner',
          start: '2019-06-12T20:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Birthday Party',
          start: '2019-06-13T07:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Click for Google',
          url: 'http://google.com/',
          start: '2019-06-28'
        }
      ]
  });
});
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventAllow would probably help you. You can check whether the event is all-day or not, and I would expect you can check whether the dropped location has a time or not. Did you research or trying anything yet?

Comment: I'm still testing out. So far, I feel this has got me what i wanted. I used `eventDrop` callback and then in that method i checked `if (delta.as('minutes') % 1440) !== 0) { revertFunc(); }` and it seems to hold my logic necessity. Don't know for sure if this is an accurate logic for the desired outcome.